# Origin of "a lot"

Tags: etymology

I am working on a novel set in the early 19th century and am wondering if the phrase "a lot" is too contemporary.

That happened a lot with debutantes, he mused.

Comment: According to the following Ngram, "a lot" was indeed used in the 19th century. It was however not used that often. "Lots", "great deal" and "tons" were used more often. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+lot%2Clots%2Cgreat+deal%2Ctons&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20lot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clots%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreat%20deal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctons%3B%2Cc0

Comment: For the plural usage (sense *lots = a **large** amount*), the full OED's first citation is 1811. Singular *I said it was **a lot** of money to fool away about such nonsense* first recorded 16 years later in 1827. But as [this NGrams shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=makes+a+lot+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmakes%20a%20lot%20of%3B%2Cc0), the usage only really took off a few decades ago.

Comment: I have just read in a George Eliot (19century) novel. "Bob had a lot much happier than hers" and at first I was confused. I thought it should have been Bob was a lot more happier than her. Until it became clear that the word Lot was originally a noun and when I say "Bob's a lot more happier" this is a short form of Bob HAS a lot more happier..a and not as it has now become, a short from of Bob IS a lot more happy.
Hence I would venture to say that your example with the debutantes is too modern.

Answer (score 2):

***lot (n.)***:  (from [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=a%20lot))

> Old English ***hlot*** "object (anything from dice to straw, but often
>   a chip of wood with a name inscribed on it) used to determine
>   someone's share," also "what falls to a person by lot," from
>   Proto-Germanic *khlutom (source also of Old Norse hlutr "lot, share,"
>   Old Frisian hlot "lot," Old Saxon hlot, Middle Dutch, Dutch lot, Old
>   High German hluz "share of land," German Los; Old English hleotan "to
>   cast lots, to foretell"), of unknown origin. The object was placed
>   with others in a receptacle, which was shaken, the winner being the
>   one that fell out first. Hence, to cast lots. In some cases the lots
>   were drawn by hand. The word was adopted from Germanic into the
>   Romanic languages (compare lottery, lotto). Meaning "choice resulting
>   from the casting of lots" first attested c. 1200.
>
> Sense of *"plot of land"* is first recorded 1630s (distribution of the
>   best property in new settlements often determined by casting lots),
>   that of "group, collection" is 1725, from notion of auction lots. ***The
>   generalized sense of "great many" is first attested in 1812.***  To cast
>   (one's) lot with another is to agree to share winnings.

Ngram ("a lot"):

[image]

Comment: +1 for this, as you beat me to it. I would suggest, then, that someone musing on debutantes in the early 19th century would be *unlikely* to use the phrase to mean "much" or "great many"; while it had entered the language, it would have been niche or perhaps even vulgar versus accepted language.

Comment: I suppose that farmers said literally "I have a lot of potatoes", as in an area of land growing potatoes. Later this came to mean "very many" in general.